# Javascript string replace with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Can someone tell me why this is not working, and the variable still holds the string with the ":" in it?

```
btn_id_postfix = "hehe:haha";
btn_id_postfix.replace(/\:/g,"");
```

Comment: It works if you save the result. Strings are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

```
btn_id_postfix=btn_id_postfix.replace(/\:/g,"");
```

replace *returns* value, but doesn't change string.

Answer (score 0):

replace doesn't change the value of the string you're modifying. What you have to do is simply to assign it to the variable.

```
btn_id_postfix = "hehe:haha";
btn_id_postfix = btn_id_postfix.replace(/\:/g,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not assigning the result to a variable. Try this:

```
btn_id_postfix = "hehe:haha";
btn_id_postfix = btn_id_postfix.replace(/\:/g,"");
```